# Can't get the options from custom field in JIRA using REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Hi I am trying get the options from custom field but always getting the results like:

```
{
   "expan":"projets",
   "projects":[]
}
```

The id for custom field is `customfield_10412` and the project key is `TCA`. Right now I am trying the below uri:

```
https://atlassian/jira/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=TCA&issuetypeNames=Test&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be you are not logged in to your Jira instance yet, therefore you gain no results returned.

Source: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Right now I am getting all the fields which are assigned to the project. is there any way can we filter to get only particular custom field. I tried using https://atlassian/jira/rest/api/2/issue/customfield_11713/editmeta but here I am getting the result like {"erroMessages":["Issue Does Not Exist"],"errors":{}}

Comment: Please can you help me how to get values of customfield_10412 from Jason response which is below.

Comment: Your editmeta doesnt work because you need this to run in the instance of an existing issue. Try is like this: atlassian/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/editmeta. This will display the options as allowedValues. However it will not just show your customfield of choice, but rather every field associated with the issue.